# What is the nature of this data structure logged to my console?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I printed out an object to my XCode console.

```
<giveItem:kl1cXLxSGC:(null)> {
    giveItemPhoto = "<giveItemPhoto:hGDYLOY5mS>";
    giveItemTitle = airplane;
    giver = "<PFUser:JvTS56BzwM>";
}
```

I understand it is showing me a giveItem object with the objectID kl1cXLxSGC, followed by three properties of the object.

What I don't understand is the (null) that directly follows the object instance declaration on the first line. What is this saying?

Comment: `kl1cXLxSGC` is not memory address, it looks more like some unique id

Comment: The `kl1cXLxSGC` is not a memory address.

Comment: Is this your own custom object? The output comes from the object's `description` method.

Comment: `kl1cXLxSGC` is likely the Parse.com objectId which is effectively a MongoDB ObjectId. It appears this is a relationship.

Comment: This is probably just `PFObject`'s implementation of `description`.

Comment: gotcha -- it seems like an object id?
Im just wondering about the "null"--- I'm having trouble getting access to the properties listed below and I'm just wondering if perhaps they are hidden behind a key I'm not aware of

Comment: This post suggests that it could be there in the event there was an "Internal Local  ID", https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-pfuser-contains-null-after-extracting-from-array

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it seems one remaining question is "how do I access the properties".

Since two of your properties are pointers, it looks like you haven't told it to include the full objects, so all you get is a pointer.

The easiest option is to tell it to include those objects in the query as follows:

```
[giveItemQuery includeKey:@"giveItemPhoto"];
[giveItemQuery includeKey:@"giver"];
```

Now you'll be able to fully access those objects and their properties.